# Switching from Hudson to Jenkins in mid 2014

Tags: jenkins, hudson

We have a Hudson Version 3.1.1 running with multiple plugins installed, and after experiencing multiple problems with some of the plugins and now even in the newest auto-update, we deem it ready to switch to Jenkins finally.

Sadly both projects developed in different directions. The official [Jenkins Wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Upgrading+from+Hudson+to+Jenkins) says that upgrading only worked up to Hudson V1.395, a version published multiple years ago. I tried that but it doesn't work does to incompatibilities between the systems.

Is there, today in mid-2014, a proven way or working tutorial how to make the switch? I'm asking for more than some basic ideas.

Comment: This is basically a question for existing documentation, which is out-of-scope-ish.

Comment: That's right, but at least I now know that there's no solution other than porting over all the projects :(